# ess-mode fails to start s-plus process correctly

Tags: linux, emacs, ess, elementary-os, s-plus

When trying to start S-plus 6.2.1 for linux using Emacs 25.2.1 lucid and ess-17.11.2 under Elementary OS 5.0 (based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), I get the following error:

```
ess-command: Wrong number of arguments: #[(com &optional buf sleep) "Á!" [com ess-eval-linewise] 2
("/usr/share/emacs25/site-lisp/ess/ess-dde.elc" . 4843)], 7
```

It seems that an S+ process is running, but when I try to issue a command, I get this error:

```
ess-get-process: No ESS process is associated with this buffer now
```

How do I fix it? I tried with ess-18.10, but got another error telling that it could not find the Splus program although it is in the PATH.

Comment: you want the latest ESS, and did you try customizing the `inferior-S+-program`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, when using ess-18.10 the `inferior-S+-program` already points to "Splus" which is in the exec-path.

Comment: so `M-x (executable-find "Splus")` finds the program?

Comment: It could not immediately find Splus, but after I made a soft link to Splus in /usr/bin, `M-x (executable-find "Splus")`finds the program "/usr/local/bin/Splus". However, I still get the error: `S: The emacs variable ‘inferior-S+-program’ does
not point to S-Plus 6 or 7 or 8.  Please add ‘splus[678]?/cmd’ (expand the
‘[678]?’ to match your setup) to your ‘exec-path’ or specify the complete
path to ‘Splus.exe’ in the variable ‘inferior-S+-program’ in your
‘.emacs’ file`

Comment: It seems to think you are on windows, what is the value of `ess-microsoft-p`

Comment: `its value is nil`. I am running Linux (Elementary OS) in a virtualbox under Mac OSX.

Comment: Yea, I don't understand what it is doing. That function is in a module that should be loaded only on windows by the looks of if.